# Attach single contact in Gmail message

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

Is there an easy way to attach contact information, much like Outlook, to my email message?

Comment: Not without exporting from your contacts. (There's an easy way if you use Android, though.)

Answer (score 2):

It takes a few steps but can be done according to the eHow article [here.](http://www.ehow.com/how_6494221_share-contacts-gmail.html) I'm not sure if you'd count it as 'easy' though because the process doesn't seem readily apparent to me.

(Here are steps from the eHow article mentioned above, in case that page changes in the future, and for easy reference.)

**Solution:**

1. Log in to your Gmail account.
2. Click "Contacts" on the left side of the page.
3. Click the "Export" link on the top right. An "Export Contacts"
   dialog box will open.
4. Select Gmail CSV to share the contacts with another Gmail account or
   Outlook CSV to share with any email service that uses
   Outlook-formatted address books, such as Apple Mail or Thunderbird.
5. Click "Export Contacts" and a "Contacts" CSV file will appear on
   your desktop.
6. Attach this file to an email and send the email to the person with
   whom you want to share your contacts. You now have shared contacts
   in Gmail.